# I am part of a group, but I cannot create files

Tags: nautilus, permissions, 13.10

I wanted to change the group of the `/var/www` directory to www-data, which I did by executing the command `sudo chown -R root:www-data /var/www`.

I then added myself to that `www-data` group by doing `sudo adduser jeroen www-data`.

To finally give the www-data group the right permissions for that directory, I did `sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www`.

When I then use Nautilus to browse to that directory, using the jeroen account, I cannot create or edit any files in it. What did I do wrong?

Comment: @dan08 You can put that up as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check that you are in the `www-data` group run `groups` in the terminal. If `www-data` does not appear in the list, logout and back in to make the change take effect.